# Better performance in MySQL subqueries for timeline graph

Tags: mysql, subquery, timeline

i have a query with subqueries for a timeline widget of participants, leads and customers.
For example with 15k rows in the table but only 2k in this date range (January 1st to January 28th) this takes about 40 seconds!

```
SELECT created_at as date, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM participant
    WHERE created_at <= date
) as participants,
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
    FROM participant
    WHERE participant_type = "lead"
    AND created_at <= date
) as leads,
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
    FROM participant
    WHERE participant_type = "customer"
    AND created_at <= date
) as customer
FROM participant
WHERE created_at >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
AND created_at <= '2016-01-28 23:59:59'
GROUP BY date(date)
```

How can i improve the performance?

The table fields are declared as follows:

```
id => primary_key, INT 10, auto increment
participant_type => ENUM "lead,customer", NULLABLE, ut8_unicode_ci
created_at => TIMESTAMP, default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: give index to the `id`

Comment: The id is already indexed as primary_key

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try using conditions within the counts (or sums) to get the values you want, having cross joined things:-

```
SELECT a.created_at as date, 
        SUM(IF(b.created_at <= a.created_at, 1, 0)) AS participants,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IF(b.participant_type = "lead" AND b.created_at <= a.created_at, b.id, NULL)) AS leads,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IF(b.participant_type = "customer" AND b.created_at <= a.created_at, b.id, NULL)) AS customer
FROM participant a
CROSS JOIN participant b
WHERE a.created_at >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
AND a.created_at <= '2016-01-28 23:59:59'
GROUP BY date(date)
```

or maybe move the date check into the join

```
SELECT a.created_at as date, 
        COUNT(b.id) AS participants,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IF(b.participant_type = "lead", b.id, NULL)) AS leads,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IF(b.participant_type = "customer", b.id, NULL)) AS customer
FROM participant a
LEFT OUTER JOIN participant b
ON b.created_at <= a.created_at
WHERE a.created_at >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
AND a.created_at <= '2016-01-28 23:59:59'
GROUP BY date(date)
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks good but the query time is much longer with these.

Comment: Can you add the table declares to your original post please?

Comment: Done this raw for the three needed fields

Comment: What are the indexes on the table?

Comment: Index is on id which is primary key. This is why id is automatically indexed.

Comment: That key will not help with this query. I suggest you need an index on created_at, and possibly an additional index covering both participant_type and created_at (in that order) would help with your original query.

Comment: I added the indexes as you mentioned but it doesn't speed up the original query.

Comment: Can you post the actual table declaration (ie, export it) and a bit of sample data please. How many participants are there in that data range?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clearly understanding what you want to do with this query. But may I can provide way for optimization.

Try this one:

```
SELECT
    participants.day as day,
    participants.total_count,
    leads.lead_count,
    customer.customer_count
FROM
    (
        SELECT created_at as day, COUNT(id) as total_count
        FROM participant
        WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-28 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY day
    ) as participants
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT  created_at as day, COUNT(DISTINCT id) as lead_count
        FROM participant
        WHERE participant_type = "lead"
        AND created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-28 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY day
    ) as leads ON (participants.day = leads.day)
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT created_at as day, COUNT(DISTINCT id) as customer_count
        FROM participant
        WHERE participant_type = "customer"
        AND WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-28 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY day
    ) as customer ON (participants.day = customer.day)
```

Comment: Thank you. But i wanted a day based graph and count up participants, leads, customer for each day. This is why the "WHERE p.created_at <= date" comes in (with the "p.created_at as date" from the outer SELECT) for each type of participant.

Comment: Sorry, I've fogot date function in sub-selects. 
_SELECT created_at as day_ shoud looks like _SELECT date(created_at) as day_,

Answer (score 0):

Add index to the query. You can execute Explain on this query.

With the help of [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html), you can see where you should add indexes to tables so that the statement executes faster by using indexes to find rows.